# How to disable source generation when using yeoman

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

when i use yo angular generator, i do not want to include all sources for plugin im downloading or whatever else be it angularjs or bootstrap and have hole bunch of script files over 30k to build my simple angular app. I know maybe it helps someone to redefine some behaviours, and something else, but i don't care about such things, i just want to have 2 version of files (minified, and unminified). And nothing else, (except license agreement ofc), is there any keys to generate only needed files, not all.
##Edit 
 Point of question is **don't include source code. Only distribution**

Comment: Yeoman asks a series of questions to determine what you want and don't want to include.

Comment: Are you serious? Question about not generating source. Read question again

Comment: May I ask why do you even care?  You have a limited disk space?

Comment: No. I'm developing for mobile platforms in html. The build time and size extremely depends on files. Right now I'm just removing mot needed files from bower dep folder. By hand. Hard work. And can make mistakes.

Comment: What are using for build automation? Grunt?

Comment: im using cordova, it doesnt have build automation.